# I have a **Rad Combo Box** in which i have two separator's .How can I remove checkbox only from separator's?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBoxSites" runat="server"
     CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true" 
     DataTextField="SiteName" DataValueField="SiteUid" 
     AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnItemDataBound= "RadComboBoxSites_ItemDataBound" 
     EmptyMessage="Please Select a site..." MaxHeight="192px"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I have a RadComboBox in which i have two separator's.  How can I remove checkbox only from separator's?

Comment: How are you adding the separators to the combobox?

Comment: RadComboBoxItem warehouseHeader = new RadComboBoxItem("--- Warehouses ---", "");
            warehouseHeader.IsSeparator = true;
          
            RadComboBoxSites.Items.Add(warehouseHeader);
            isWarehouseHeaderAdded = true;

Comment: @jacksonjohn, Please check out an answer I have just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove check boxes from `separator` items by adding the following JavaScript to your page. You have to have jquery included in your web page for this to work.

**Remove checkboxes from separator items**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function pageLoad() {
             $(".rcbItem.rcbSeparator :checkbox").remove();
      }

</script>
```

Also, I would advise you to style separator items appropriately so they look different from regular  items.  You can use something like below for this.

**Style the separator item**

```
   <head>
    <style>
    .rcbSeparator
     {
         color: red !important;
         margin-left:10px !important;
     }
    </style>
   </head>
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to avoid a separator item from being checked then attach the client-side event handler for `OnClientItemChecking` to the `radomboBox` as shown in markup below. Add the event handler script also to your page.

*Markup for Subscribing to OnClientItemChecking event*

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2" runat="server" Width="300px" Skin="Metro" 
    MaxHeight="400px" CheckBoxes="true" OnClientItemChecking="OnClientItemChecking" 
    EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true" ></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

*JavaScript that will prevent checked count from increasing when separator item is clicked*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function OnClientItemChecking(sender, args) {
                if (args.get_item().get_isSeparator() === true) {
                    args.set_cancel(true);
                }
            }
</script>
```

Comment: while clicking Separator's item checked count is increasing in Radcombox . how to get rid from this issue.

Comment: @jacksonjohn, I have added `UPDATE 1` in response to your question about checked item count increasing by 1 on clicking the separator item. This should work as I have verified on my end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't a direct setting for this, but a few workarounds:

- http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-disable-and-hide-a-single-checkbox
- http://www.telerik.com/forums/remove-checkbox-from-first-item-in-combobox